# Play a Video on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'd like to be able to do what Youtube does, play a video when the page is focused. I've tried using onblur and onfocus handlers, but they only fire during a change, and not when the initial page is loaded.

This means that when the page loads, I don't know whether or not its focused.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you interested in calling your function as soon as the page loads, as soon as the page has focus, or as soon as some element has focus? I looked at how Youtube triggers their video playback and it doesn't appear to be tied to the focus event.

Comment: I'm looking to call my function as soon as the page has focus, Youtube used to trigger video playback on page focus, looks like they've moved away from that.

Comment: I've been messing around with document.hasFocus() but sometimes when I am using window.location = "some other page on my site", document.hasFocus() is returning false when it should be true, so it's not working well for me.